# JavaScript Logging Library (with log levels)

Tags: mobile, logging, javascript

Can you recommend an easy JavaScript logging (with log levels) library?

It will be good if I can see logs when testing my application with mobile devices.

Comment: In my opinion there is no need to use an extra library for logging because the console in chrome dev tools offers all you need. Use for example consol.info("foo"). If you want you can include a time stamp and change the log level using corresponding chrome settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Log4JS](http://stritti.github.io/log4js/)

You can also use console.log on both Android and iOS.

On iOS, turn on developer tools from the Safari options in the Settings app. You'll have to keep your messages short though since it truncates. [More details from Apple here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH3-SW4)

For Android install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com) and install any of the SDK software packages from `[sdk base]/tools/android`.

Plug your phone into your computer andgo to `[sdk base]/platform_tools/` and run `adb devices`.  You'll see which Android devices are connected.  If there is only one, you can just run the logcat command `adb logcat`.  I find it helpful to use grep `adb logcat | grep -i console` and you'll see all the console.log messages in your website.  [More details from the Android developer site here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html)

Comment: The URL has changed: http://stritti.github.io/log4js/

Answer (score 3):

Try [loglevel](https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel) (full disclosure: I'm the creator of loglevel).

It's an easy minimal logging library including only the bare essentials (i.e. log levels and little else), and underneath it's (very carefully, for compatibility) internally just logging to console.log and friends where available, so output will end up in the system log, as described in tkone's answer.

For developing you should also check out [weinre](http://people.apache.org/%7Epmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/), which lets you get directly at the console of your app running on live devices, for debugging etc (hosted public instance available at [debug.phonegap.com](http://debug.phonegap.com/), or you can run it locally yourself to make it a little quicker).

Answer (score 1):

[Log.js](https://github.com/siman/log.js) is a JavaScript logging framework with log levels. I have created this one because all other JS logging frameworks I have found did not satisfy me.

Usage:

```
var myLog = LogJS.get({name: "MyLog", level: "trace", enabled: true});
myLog.info("Hello, Log");
```

If you pass a message as a function - it will be evaluated only if appropriate logging level is enabled:

```
myLog.trace(function() {
    return "Current log level is: " + myLog.getLevel();
});
```

If you don't want to bother with creating a new logger and just want to log something quickly, the here is a default logger `LogJS.root` that can be used the same way:

```
LogJS.root.error("Something bad...");
```